# What is the difference between elasticity and stiffness?

Tags: material-science, elasticity, stress-strain

Modulus of elasticity indicates Elasticity(E) but stiffness(specifically in case of axial deformations) is given as EA/L where A is area and L is length of body. These expressions led me to believe that there is a difference between them in the sense that elasticity is of the materials with which the body is made up of and depends on bond strength of material but stiffness is of a body and depends on body's dimensions as well as material with which it is made up of. But in many places I have seen them being used interchangeably.

So my doubt is -

1. is there any difference between them or are they same? If there is a difference, why are they being used interchangeably and what does each signify? And if they are same then in what sense are they same?
2. if there is some difference b/w them then how will you see them on stress - strain diagram?
3. can stiffness be considered as slope of load-deformation curve as stiffness = load/deformation, since E is the slope of stress strain curve below the proportional limit?
4. what is the difference between stretchiness, flexibility and ductility of a material?(and plz donot give the textbook definition of flexibility as ability to bend. This is what created this confusion. I'm unable to comprehend what is meant by bend here. Is bend used here to describe all types of general deformation or just bending like in case of beam bending?)
5. EA is called axial rigidity, what does rigidity here signify? Can rigidity be considered as a body having infinite stiffness(ofcourse, theoretically) on a scale of stiffness ranging between flexible to rigid?

PS - I've been trying to find these for quite some time but it is leading to more and more confusion. I would appreciate an intuitive explanation, if possible. Also I'm a non native speaker, so sorry for any grammatical errors or if my language seems rude.

Answer (score 1):

Confusion can often be resolved by examining the physical units in which quantities are expressed. Since stiffness and elasticity are expressed in different units, they cannot be the same thing.

You are correct in believing that elasticity is a property of a material, while stiffness is a property of an object/material combination. Elasticity (technically the elastic modulus) is expressed in units of force/area, or $N/m^2$ in the SI system, while stiffness (a.k.a. spring constant "k") is expressed in units of force/length, or N/m in the SI system. (The inverse of stiffness is compliance and would be espressed in units of m/N).

Technically, compliance (the inverse of stiffness) would be the slope of a load deformation curve (assuming load in Newtons is on the x-axis and deformation in meters is on the y-axis).

Bending is a deformation of object in response to a force applied perpendicular to it's longitudinal (or longest) dimension (transverse deformation). Unlike a spring, which is usually conceived as deforming in line with it's longitudinal axis (axial deformation). Elasticity is a material property that quantitatively relates both types of deformation to their respective applied loads.

Axial rigidity, like stiffness, is a property of an object/material combination. I haven't read any particularly helpful mental models for this quantity, but I personally tend toward thinking of it as stress per unit length of the object.

Flexibility and stretchiness are not numerically defined properties in engineering, so cannot be discussed with precision.

Ductility is not related to elasticity. Ductility is a dimensionless material property that measures how much a material can be stretched (in terms of length, or $\Delta L/L$) before it breaks, whereas elasticity expresses how difficult it is (i.e. how much force is required) to stretch the material.